How to prevent multiple clicks in Jetpack Compose to avoid navigating to the same screen multiple times?
I'm building a Jetpack Compose app, and I have a button that navigates to the Home screen using a NavController. The issue is that when the user clicks the button multiple times in quick succession, it causes the app to navigate to the same screen multiple times, which is not the desired behavior.
Note: Without isButtonEnabled flag or Button enable/disable state any technique
Button(onClick = {
    navController.navigate("home")
}) {
    Text("Go to Home")
}


You can refer this

Your looking to "debounce" your button.

dropUnlessResumed is the API you are looking for

If you are using lifecycle version 2.8.0 or up, you can use dropUnlessResumed API, or you can implement your own debounce logic for preventing multiple clicks with quick succession.
